# Passing parameters to \g@addto@macro

Tags: macros, parameters

I'm a complete newbie but have a little background in programming. I've been looking at a [MWE located here](https://github.com/yannisl/MWE/blob/master/imagedb-test01.tex) provided by [Yiannis Lazarides](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/963/yiannis-lazarides).

In the macro definition, we have

```
%% add an image to the DB, use the LaTeX macro
%% \g@addto@macro to store them at the DB location
\def\addtoDB#1#2{%
    \ifx\@empty#1
        \g@addto@macro{#1}{#2}
    \else
        \g@addto@macro#1{,#2}
    \fi
}
```

What is the difference between `\g@addto@macro{#1}{#2}` and `\g@addto@macro#1{,#2}` ?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I believe that the macro is aimed to build a comma separated list of items. When the first item is added, no comma is wanted.

Comment: @egreg Did you mean 'when the first item is empty'?

Comment: @cfr No, it's what I wrote: `#1` is a macro name, that corresponds to the list to which some item has to be added.

Comment: @egreg Ah, now I see. Thanks. It is when the first argument is empty, where the first argument is the existing list...

Comment: @cfr If the first argument is empty, `\@empty` would be compared to `\g@addto@macro`, resulting in a disaster.

Comment: @egreg I didn't put it very well.

Answer (score 6):

The macro is aimed to incrementally build a list macro; in the document you find something like

```
\def\alist{fig167,fig168,fig169,fig176,%
  fig180,fig181,fig182,fig183,fig185,fig186,fig187,fig188}
```

Well, one can obtain the same result by

```
\newDB{alist}
```

and then

```
\addtoDB\alist{fig167}
\addtoDB\alist{fig168}
\addtoDB\alist{fig169}
\addtoDB\alist{fig176}
```

and so on.

At the first `\addtoDB` call, the macro `\alist` defined by `\newDB` is still empty, so the conditional is true and

```
\g@addto@macro\alist{fig167}
```

is executed. At the second macro call, `\alist` is not empty, so

```
\g@addto@macro\alist{,fig168}
```

is executed, resulting in `\alist` expanding to `fig167,fig168`. And so on for the successive calls.

Answer (score 2):

In this particular case I think the two uses of `\g@addto@macro` are meant to be the same apart from the extra comma prepended to the second argument in the second case. In fact since the first argument of `\g@addto@macro` is meant to be simply the name of a macro, the brackets of the first case are not strictly necessary. However, for reasons we'll see in a second, they are a good precaution and, in my opinion, should be used in the second case as well.

To illustrate the difference they make in general (when the first argument is not necessarily a macro name) let's consider the following example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\def\test#1#2{this #1 is #2 a test}
\def\testA#1#2{A \test{#1}{#2} A}
\def\testB#1#2{B \test#1{#2} B}

\begin{document}
 \testA{{1}{2}}{3}

 \testB{{1}{2}}{3}
\end{document}
```

The `\test` macro takes two arguments, `\testA` uses `\test` as in your first case (with brackets around `#1`) while `\testB` uses `\test` as in your second case.

In the body we use `\testA` and `\testB` with the same two arguments: `#1 = {1}{2}` and `#2 = 3`.

Since `\testA` uses brackets around `#1`, it expands to `A \test{{1}{2}}{3} A`, as expected, binding `{1}{2}` to the first argument of `\test`.
`\testB`, instead, expands to `B \test{1}{2}{3} B` which means that `\test` will get `1` as first argument and `2` as second argument; `{3}` is not consumed by `\test` and gets typeset after `\test` is expanded.

Hence the output is

> A this 12 is 3 a test A
>
> B this 1 is 2 a test3 B