# How can I loop thru a list of inputs that come after \maketitle, yet use that list as part of the \maketitle command?

Tags: tikz-pgf, languages, programming, loops, literate-programming

## Multilingual Document

## Question

I would like to follow the [principle of "don't repeat yourself"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) and create a single list of inputs, which are actually various versions of the same document in different languages. [This question is related to this.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/231055/how-can-i-create-a-list-as-a-variable-that-can-be-appended-and-eventually-typese)

---

This question is part of a trail of questions. The goal mine was to use this list inside of a `tikz` node, but I removed that from this question in the interest of keeping it simple. So, for those interested, *here is a quick list for reference*:

**Related Question for making a macro that can handle post-parsing-inputted list items, see:**

- [How can I create a list as a variable that can be appended and eventually typeset?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/231055/how-can-i-create-a-list-as-a-variable-that-can-be-appended-and-eventually-typese)

**For that same solution with `tikz` node support, see:**

- [How can I use a list stored in aux and insert its output into a tikz node?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/232067/how-can-i-use-a-list-stored-in-aux-and-insert-its-output-into-a-tikz-node)

---

## UPDATE 2015-03-08: The following code based on egreg's answer

### works 50% of the time

see [How can I use a list stored in aux and insert its output into a tikz node?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/232067/how-can-i-use-a-list-stored-in-aux-and-insert-its-output-into-a-tikz-node)

## Situation

I'd like to create a command that has:

- iso 639-1 code as #1
- language name in native tongue as #2
- input file as #3

example: `\inputlanguagefile{En}{English}{./Languages/en.tex}`

Then I would like to create a list of the language codes from these inputs that can be used in my custom `\maketitle` command (*warning: \maketitle inputs are sent directly to `tikz` nodes*)

## Problem

The difficulty lies in the fact that the list is called before it is created. I would probably need to create some kind of command to loop through the inputs beforehand. The document would look something like this:

```
%\maketitle[subtitle]{title}
\maketitle[listoflanguagecodes]{Multilingual Document}
\inputlanguagefile{En}{English}{./Languages/en.tex}
\inputlanguagefile{Da}{Dansk}{./Languages/da.tex}
\inputlanguagefile{De}{Deutsch}{./Languages/de.tex}
\inputlanguagefile{It}{Italiano}{./Languages/it.tex}
\inputlanguagefile{Hu}{Magyarország}{./Languages/hu.tex}
```

## Redefined \maketitle

\maketitle[subtitle]{title}
\maketitle[\listoflanguagecodes]{Title}

```
\renewcommand{\maketitle}[2][]{%
\thispagestyle{empty}
 #1\\
 #2
\clearpage
\setcounter{page}{1}
}%
```

The second argument i.e. the actual language names are only used to create a language directory with `etoc`.

## MWE

I am trying to put together a minimal working example of a complex setup. **Work in progress.**

```
autolanglist/
├── Languages
│   ├── da.tex
│   ├── de.tex
│   └── en.tex
└── usermanual.tex
```

1 directory, 4 files

### Contents usermanual.tex

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,positioning}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{etoc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcounter{runningsectioncounter}
\setcounter{runningsectioncounter}{0}
\titleformat{\section}[hang]{\color{red}\Huge\bfseries}{}{0pt}{\thesection\quad#1}[\stepcounter{runningsectioncounter}]

% Use this \newlangfile{<code>}{<name>}{<file>} to add external language varieties
\newcommand{\inputlanguagefile}[3]{%
  \newpage\pdfbookmark{#2}{bkm#1}%
  \etoctoccontentsline{part}{#2}%
  \setcounter{runningsectioncounter}{\value{section}}
  \setcounter{section}{0}
  \renewcommand*{\theHsection}{chX.\the\value{runningsectioncounter}} % Keeps hyperref happy (provides unique section numbers instead of using the section counter)
  \input{#3}%
}

\renewcommand{\maketitle}[2][]{%
    #1\\
    #2
       
\clearpage
}%

\newcommand{\usermanualfrontmatter}{%
    \maketitle[En, Da, De]{User Manual} % NOTE: This is the list of language codes should be automated!
    \newpage
    \setcounter{tocdepth}{0} % make ToC contain only parts
    \renewcommand{\contentsname}{Language Directory} % change ToC Title
    \tableofcontents
    \newpage
    \setcounter{tocdepth}{4}
    \renewcommand{\contentsname}{Table of Contents} % reset ToC Title back to default
}%

\begin{document}
\usermanualfrontmatter{}
\inputlanguagefile{En}{English}{./Languages/en.tex}
\inputlanguagefile{Da}{Dansk}{./Languages/da.tex}
\inputlanguagefile{De}{Deutsch}{./Languages/de.tex}
\end{document}
```

#### Contents of ./Languages/da.tex

```
\maketitle[da]{Brugsanvisning}
\newpage
\localtableofcontents
\newpage
\section{Test}
\lipsum[50]
```

#### Contents of ./Languages/de.tex

```
\maketitle[de]{Gebrauchsanweisung}
\newpage
\localtableofcontents
\newpage
\section{Test}
\lipsum[50]
```

#### Contents of ./Languages/en.tex

```
\maketitle[en]{User Manual}
\localtableofcontents
\clearpage
\section{Test}
\lipsum[50]
```

## Output

The first page is scaled down A4 paper, but the rest were resized too 100mm x 150mm to save screen real estate on this website :) I attempted to clearly show which list should be generated automatically. The contents of which are not added until later in the document (`\inputlanguagefile`).

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I don't think that such an extensive change to your question is along the guidelines of the site. One should avoid edits that invalidate existing answers.

Comment: Alright. I was actually opening a new question as you typed that. It seems like the question is becoming convoluted. You are right.

Comment: @cfr I meant to do that yesterday but fell asleep. Now it should be restored to a pre-tikz state where egreg's answer applies.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to write the data in the `.aux` file for having the information available at the next run; we exploit the fact that the `.aux` file is read as part of `\begin{document}`, so `\manuallanguages` will have the requested value (at the next run) when `\maketitle` is issued.

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter 
\newcommand{\manuallanguages}{\@gobble} % initialization
\newcommand{\inputlanguagefile}[1]{%
  \input{\manualfile{#1}}%
  \protected@write\@auxout{}{\string\used@language{#1}}%
}
\AtEndDocument{\let\used@language\@gobble}
\newcommand{\used@language}[1]{%
  \g@addto@macro\manuallanguages{\language@sep\format@language{#1}}%
}
\newcommand{\language@sep}{, }% separator
\newcommand{\format@language}[1]{%
  \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\@secondoftwo % or \@firstoftwo
  \csname language@#1\endcsname
}
\newcommand\definemanuallanguage[2]{%
  \@namedef{language@#1}{{#1}{#2}}%
}
\makeatother

\newcommand\manualfile[1]{./UserManual_#1}% use your own

\definemanuallanguage{en}{English}
\definemanuallanguage{de}{Deutsch}
\definemanuallanguage{da}{Dansk}

\begin{document}

\title{User Manuals\\
  \manuallanguages}

\author{macmadness86}

\maketitle

\inputlanguagefile{en}

\inputlanguagefile{da}

\inputlanguagefile{de}

\end{document}
```

Each `\inputlanguagefile` adds a note in the `.aux` file in the form

```
\used@language{xy}
```

where `xy` is the argument to `\inputlanguagefile`.

Define `\manualfile` to work according to your setup, here I have the manual files in the same directory as the main file.

If you prefer to have just the ISO abbreviations (which are lowercase), change `\@secondoftwo` into `\@firstoftwo`.

[image]

Comment: So, do you have any options that are less verbose :D

Comment: I am struggling to keep my commands the way they are and make this work. I know it is possible now. I have a redefined `\maketitle` command that accepts an optional argument as its subtitle. I will post the code above. Maybe you can help me if it isn't too much trouble.

Comment: @macmadness86 `\title[\manuallanguages]{User Manuals}` should work.

Comment: It works without `tikz`. I think the problem I am having deals with the @gobble and my `\maketitle` command, which contains `\tikz` nodes. I get `! Argument of \@gobble has an extra }` I will try to reproduce the problem and put some code in my question.

Comment: Would you mind having a look at my new MWE? My knowledge is not advanced enough to understand your answer. i.e. \inputlanguagefile[1] should be \inputlanguagefile[3]. I don't know where to go from there...

Comment: I am having trouble understanding the `\format@language`  command. What does it do? Could you also either explain why there are 3 `\expandafter` commands followed by a `\@secondoftwo`?

Comment: For anybody reading this, I understand how to make the list by reading a different answer from egreg: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/152187/13552

Comment: Could you please explain why the first argument of `@auxout` is empty `{}`? in `\@auxout{}{\string\used@language{#1}}`?

Answer (score 2):

**last update:** shows how to adapt the concrete code which was added to the Question in an edit. See bottom.

As you mentioned [etoc](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/etoc), I will explain that with it you can achieve what you want without having to write things to  the `aux` file.

I have also added `hyperref` just to show that hyperlinks will be there.

The idea is that with `etoc` you can print your comma separated list of used languages via the command `\tableofcontents`, and placing this command as a node in  a `TikZ` picture is no problem.

Update adds a variant.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, positioning}

\usepackage{etoc}

% in this example, user manuals are each printed in their own
% \part. If there were no other parts, we would not need to define 
% a special division called "languagefile", we would simply use "part".

% I use a \part below in \inputlanguagefile
% to provide an hyperref target.

% Else, without \part, one would only need define a counter 
% and do \refstepcounter in the \inputlanguagefile command.

% Without hyperref, there is no need to do anything extra.
\etocsetlevel{languagefile}{6}

\usepackage{hyperref}% just to check compatibility

\makeatletter

\newcommand\manualfile[1]% #1 = typically, two-letter abbrev for language
           {./UserManual_#1.tex }% use your own preferred location


\newcommand\declaremanuallanguage[2]% #1 = abbrev, #2 = full name
          {\@namedef{languagename@#1}{#2}}


\newcommand{\inputlanguagefile}[1]{%
     \part{\@nameuse{languagename@#1}}
     \etoctoccontentsline{languagefile}{\@nameuse{languagename@#1}}%
     \input{\manualfile{#1}}}

\makeatother

\declaremanuallanguage{en}{English}
\declaremanuallanguage{de}{Deutsch}
\declaremanuallanguage{da}{Dansk}

\newcommand{\manuallanguages}{%
    \begingroup
      \etocsetnexttocdepth {-1}% limit the TOC to what we want
      \etocsetlevel {part}{0}% move parts out of the way
      \etocsetlevel {languagefile}{-1}% only interested in them
      \etocsetstyle {languagefile}
                    % do the trick to get a separator, this is executed once
                    {\def\manual@sep{\def\manual@sep{, }}}
                    % then each entry will do ", " except the first
                    {\manual@sep\etocname}{}{}%
      \etocsettocstyle {}{}% suppress standard Contents heading
% we will be in vertical mode.
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node [font=\Huge\bfseries] (title) at 
      ($ (current page.north)!.25!(current page.south) $) {User manuals};
    \node [font=\Large\bfseries] (subtitle) [below= 2cm of title] 
          {\tableofcontents};% etoc's magic ! Each entry is a link.
\end{tikzpicture}
    \endgroup
%\clearpage
\setcounter{page}{1}
}%


% only for sample code, remove from final version
% as we don't provide an extension, .tex  suffix is appended.
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{UserManual_en}
This is the English manual.
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{UserManual_de}
Dies ist die deutsche Bedienungsanleitung.
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{UserManual_da}
Dette er den danske manual.
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{UserManual_fr}
Ceci est le manuel français.
\end{filecontents}

\title{\manuallanguages}

\author{macmadness86}

\begin{document}\pagestyle{empty}% only for cropping pages for png's

\maketitle\thispagestyle{empty}

\vskip1cm
\hrule
\clearpage

\inputlanguagefile{en}

\vskip1cm
\hrule
\clearpage

\inputlanguagefile{da}

\vskip1cm
\hrule
\clearpage

\inputlanguagefile{de}
\vskip1cm
\hrule

\end{document}
```

> [image: first page]
>   [image: second page]
>   [image: third page]
>   [image: fourth page]

(the rules are only for the pages to be the same width even after cropping to produce the images)

Variant:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, positioning}

\usepackage{etoc}

\usepackage{hyperref}% just to check compatibility

% location of user manuals
\newcommand\manualfile[1]{./UserManualv2_#1.tex }%

% innocent wrapper
\newcommand{\inputlanguagefile}[1]{\input{\manualfile{#1}}}

% a fictional sectioning unit,
\etocsetlevel{languagefile}{6}

\newcommand{\thisismanualfor}[1]{% 
    \part{#1}% convenient way to create an hyperref target
    \etoctoccontentsline{languagefile}{#1}%
}%

\newcommand{\manuallanguages}{%
    \begingroup
      \etocsetnexttocdepth {-1}% limit the TOC to what we want
      \etocsetlevel {part}{0}% move parts out of the way
      \etocsetlevel {languagefile}{-1}% only interested in them
      \etocsetstyle {languagefile}
                    % do the trick to get a separator, this is executed once
                    {\def\manual@sep{\def\manual@sep{, }}}
                    % then each entry will do ", " except the first
                    {\manual@sep\etocname}{}{}%
      \etocsettocstyle {}{}% suppress standard Contents heading
% for the record: etoc always does a \par when doing \tableofcontents,
% which can be turned off via \etocinline command; it turns out
% we don't need to worry about this in the TikZ's node.
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node [font=\Huge\bfseries] (title) at 
      ($ (current page.north)!.25!(current page.south) $) {User manuals};
    \node [font=\Large\bfseries] (subtitle) [below= .5cm of title] 
          {\tableofcontents};% etoc's magic ! Each entry is a link.
\end{tikzpicture}
    \endgroup
}%


% ONLY for sample code, REMOVE from final version
% as we don't provide an extension, .tex  suffix is appended.
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{UserManualv2_en}
\thisismanualfor{English}%
This is the English manual.
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{UserManualv2_de}
\thisismanualfor{Deutsch}%
Dies ist die deutsche Bedienungsanleitung.
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{UserManualv2_da}
\thisismanualfor{Dansk}%
Dette er den danske manual.
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{UserManualv2_fr}
\thisismanualfor{Français}%
Ceci est le manuel français.
\end{filecontents}

\title{\manuallanguages}

\author{macmadness86}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\part{Introduction}

\inputlanguagefile{fr}

\inputlanguagefile{en}

\inputlanguagefile{da}

\part{Conclusion}

\hrule

\end{document}
```

> [image: etoc to list automatically input files]

---

Now that the question has complete code sample I can provide an answer addressing more directly the specific aims.

This is a copy of the code with additions tagged by `% ADD THIS` lines.

```
\documentclass{article}
%% \usepackage{fontspec} % commented out to compile with pdflatex
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,positioning}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{etoc}
% ADDTHIS
    \etocsetlevel{languageabbrev}{6}
%
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcounter{runningsectioncounter}
\setcounter{runningsectioncounter}{0}
\titleformat{\section}[hang]{\color{red}\Huge\bfseries}{}{0pt}{\thesection\quad#1}[\stepcounter{runningsectioncounter}]

% Use this \newlangfile{<code>}{<name>}{<file>} to add external language varieties
\newcommand{\inputlanguagefile}[3]{%
  \newpage\pdfbookmark{#2}{bkm#1}%
  \etoctoccontentsline{part}{#2}%
% ADDTHIS
\etoctoccontentsline{languageabbrev}{#1}%
%
  \setcounter{runningsectioncounter}{\value{section}}
  \setcounter{section}{0}
  \renewcommand*{\theHsection}{chX.\the\value{runningsectioncounter}} % Keeps hyperref happy (provides unique section numbers instead of using the section counter)
  \input{#3}%
}

\renewcommand{\maketitle}[2][]{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
        \node [font=\Huge] (title) at ($ (current page.north)!.25!(current page.south) $) {#2};
        \node [font=\Large,below=2cm of title] (subtitle) {#1};
        %\node [color=red,draw,below=1cm of subtitle] (note) {This list should be generated automatically.};
        %\draw [->,ultra thick,red] (note) -- (subtitle);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\clearpage
}%

\newcommand{\usermanualfrontmatter}{%
% ADDTHIS
    \GetUsedLanguages
%
    \maketitle[\UsedLanguages]{User Manual}
    \newpage
    \setcounter{tocdepth}{0} % make ToC contain only parts
    \renewcommand{\contentsname}{Language Directory} % change ToC Title
    \tableofcontents
    \newpage
    \setcounter{tocdepth}{4}
    \renewcommand{\contentsname}{Table of Contents} % reset ToC Title back to default
}%

% ADDTHIS
\makeatletter % to use \g@addto@macro from LaTeX's kernel
\newcommand{\GetUsedLanguages}{%
  \begingroup % work in a group to undo our changes automatically on exit
      \etocsetnexttocdepth {-1}% limit the TOC to what we want
      \etocsetlevel {part}{0}% move parts out of the way
      \etocsetlevel {languageabbrev}{-1}% only interested in them
      \etocsetstyle {languageabbrev}
                    {\gdef\UsedLanguages{}\etocskipfirstprefix}
                    {\g@addto@macro\UsedLanguages{, }}
                    {\expandafter\g@addto@macro\expandafter\UsedLanguages
                     \expandafter{\etocthename}}%
                    {}%
      \etocsettocstyle {}{}% suppress standard Contents heading
      \etocinline % suppress \par, thus TOC does not typeset anything at all
      \tableofcontents % fill up \UsedLanguages
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother



% ONLY FOR ALL IN ONE CODE SAMPLE
%
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{da.tex}
\maketitle[da]{Brugsanvisning}
\newpage
\localtableofcontents
\newpage
\section{Test}
\lipsum[50]
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{de.tex}
\maketitle[de]{Gebrauchsanweisung}
\newpage
\localtableofcontents
\newpage
\section{Test}
\lipsum[50]
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{en.tex}
\maketitle[en]{User Manual}
\localtableofcontents
\clearpage
\section{Test}
\lipsum[50]
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\usermanualfrontmatter{}
\inputlanguagefile{En}{English}{./en.tex}
\inputlanguagefile{Da}{Dansk}{./da.tex}
\inputlanguagefile{De}{Deutsch}{./de.tex}
\end{document}
```

> [image: etoc title with languages]

Comment: Cool answer! I have to emphasize though that I am looking for a solution following the "don't repeat yourself' principle. i.e. I am very against these declarations. I just want one command to call each file, its language code and corresponding language name.

Comment: do you mean the `filecontents` declarations? there are only there to allow people to copy-paste the code if they want to test it, with no need of manually creating the files. If however, you mean the `\declaremanuallanguage`, their only rôle is to map abbreviations to full names. If the `\etoctoccontentsline` things are moved to *inside* the respective language manuals, then nothing at all will be in the main `.tex` file, only the `\input` instructions.

Comment: @macmadness86 I think jfbu forgot to ping you...?

Comment: @jfbu I meant the `\declaremanuallanguage`. But Actually, I am not looking for an answer with `etoc`—so sorry about that! You clearly put some time into your answer. This is because I have many documents that are not compatible with `etoc`. Nonetheless, your answer is nice. I was hoping to draw more attention to this queston by starting a bounty.

Comment: @macmadness86 no need to be sorry :-), I understand. My question here was actually before I posted the last update to my answer which used the code you added to your question. The main incompatibility I know for `etoc` is with beamer class.

Comment: @macmadness86 thanks for the undeserved bounty, and sorry I can not address your exact concerns.